# ASP Contact form Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I took a simple form from the net and placed it in a website to use as a contact form, alls well, it looks okay, but when I submit the form, I get this error.
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/new/contactusprocess.asp, line 31

800401f3

---

This is the code

```
<%
Dim error
error = 0
For Each f In Request.Form
  If Request.Form(f) = "" Then 
    error = 1
  End If
Next
If error=1 Then
  response.redirect "error.html"
Else
Dim f, emsg, mail_to, r, o, c, other
fline = "_______________________________________________________________________"& vbNewLine   
hline = vbNewLine & "_____________________________________"& vbNewLine   
emsg = ""

For Each f In Request.Form
   If mid(f,1,1)<>"S"  = True Then 'do not save if input name starts with S
     emsg  = emsg & f & " = " &  Trim(Request.Form(f)) & hline
   End If
Next

Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
    objNewMail.From = Request("Email Address")
    objNewMail.Subject = "Message from contact page (version: 1.0)"
    objNewMail.To = mail_to
    objNewMail.Body = emsg & fline
    objNewMail.Send
    Set objNewMail = Nothing

response.redirect "thankyou.html"
End if
%>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The server you're on doesn't have the `CDONTS` libraries. Suggest using `CDO.Message` instead.
Confirm with your host that they support sending email from classic ASP.

Replace your code (from line containing CDONTS, up to + including Response.Redirect) with this code.

```
   Dim  to, from, subj, body
   from = Request("Email Address")
   subj = "Message from contact page (version: 1.0)"

   SendMail(subj, from, mail_to, emsg & fline)
   Response.Redirect "thankyou.html"
End If

'******* a method to encapsulate our emailing functionality
Sub SendMail(subject, from, to, body)
    Dim sConfURL, cdoConfig, cdoMessage 

    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 
    sConfURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
    With cdoConfig.Fields 
        .Item(sConfURL & "sendusing") = 2
        ,Item(sConfURL & "smtpserver") = "localhost"
        .Item(sConfURL & "smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update 
    End With

    Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

    With cdoMessage
        Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 'may have to remove the Set if an error here.
        .From = from
        .To = to
        .Subject = subject
        .TextBody = body
        .Send
    End With

    Set cdoMessage = Nothing 
    Set cdoConfig = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there thanks, this is very different to my asp, what html should I include here , to show the form? My html doesnt accommodate for your changes, thanks for the help

Comment: @Sarah: there's no HTML involved here; I've refactored the answer to help you paste into your code. You'll have to ensure that it suits your application. This is meant to replace your non-working CDONTS-based code.

Comment: Just for completeness of answer, it's worth mentioning that CDONTS was last included in Windows 2000, so the OP's host is not at fault here for not including/supporting it.

Comment: I still get this error

Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03f2'

Expected identifier

/new/contactusprocess.asp, line 10

Dim  to, from, subj, body
-----^

Comment: @Sarah: what exactly is on line 10?